# How to copy generated signature in HTML,CSS into outlook 2016 with correct styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-email, signature

I designed a template for a signature generator and uploaded it to my website's server, (example website.com/signatures). However, when I copy the signature from the server and use it in Outlook, the CSS styling doesn't appear. Only the images and fields are copied without the accompanying CSS. How can I configure Outlook or modify the code to ensure that the signature appears the same way with all its styling in Outlook?

```js
    document.getElementById('signature-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // Get form input values
      var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
      var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
      var job = document.getElementById('job').value;
      var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

      // Update signature output
      var signatureOutput = document.getElementById('signature-output');
      signatureOutput.querySelector('.name-surname').textContent = name + ' ' + surname;
      signatureOutput.querySelector('.job-desc').textContent = job;
      signatureOutput.querySelector('.phone').textContent = phone;

      // Scroll to the signature output
      signatureOutput.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    });

    document.getElementById('copy-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      var signatureOutput = document.getElementById('signature-output');
      
      // Create a range and select the signature output content
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(signatureOutput);
      
      // Copy the content to the clipboard
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
      document.execCommand('copy');
      
      // Deselect the content
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      
      // Show a success message
      alert('Signature copied to clipboard!');
    });
```

```css
.rectangle {
      position: absolute;
      width: 486px;
      height: 160px;
      left: 67px;
      top: 331px;
      background: #F0F9F5;
      border-radius: 8px;
    }
    
    .name-surname {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 18px;
      left: 87px;
      top: 347px;
      font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 18px;
      color: #3B785A;
    }
    
    .job-desc {
      position: absolute;
      width: 160px;
      height: 18px;
      left: 87px;
      top: 369px;
      font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 18px;
      color: #3B785A;
    }
    
    .phone {
      position: absolute;
      width: 120px;
      height: 18px;
      left: 87px;
      top: 391px;
      font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 18px;
      color: #3B785A;
    }
    
    .social-layout {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0px;
      gap: 16px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 80px;
      height: 16px;
      left: 87px;
      top: 434px;
    }
    
    .logo-linkedin {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      flex: none;
      order: 0;
      flex-grow: 0;
    }
    
    .logo-youtube {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      flex: none;
      order: 1;
      flex-grow: 0;
    }
    
    .logo-facebook {
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      flex: none;
      order: 2;
      flex-grow: 0;
    }
    
    .hyperlinkurl {
      position: absolute;
      width: 128px;
      height: 17px;
      left: 87px;
      top: 458px;
      font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 17px;
      text-decoration-line: underline;
      color: #3B785A;
    }
    
    .logomg {
      position: absolute;
      width: 73.92px;
      height: 48px;
      left: 463px;
      top: 427px;
    }
    
    .map-gradient {
      position: absolute;
      width: 307.92px;
      height: 160px;
      left: 201px;
      top: 331px;
      background: url(map-gradient.png);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
  
  <form id="signature-form">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" required>
    <input type="text" id="job" placeholder="Job" required>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
    <button type="submit">Generate</button>
  </form>

  <div id="signature-output" class="signature-output">
    <span class="name-surname"></span>
    <span class="job-desc"></span>
    <span class="phone"></span>
  
    <div class="social-layout">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
        <img src="logo-linkedin.png" alt="logo-linkedin" class="logo-linkedin">
      </a>

      <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
        <img src="logo-youtube.png" alt="logo-youtube" class="logo-youtube">
      </a>

      <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
        <img src="logo-facebook.png" alt="logo-facebook" class="logo-facebook">
      </a>
    </div>
  
    <a href="#" class="hyperlinkurl">WebsiteUrl.com</a>
  
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logomg">
  
    <div class="map-gradient"></div>
  </div>

  <button id="copy-button">Copy Signature</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if by "copy" you mean you're copying the code to your email signature or you're selecting the signature in a browser and literally copy/pasting (sounds like the latter), but the culprit here is likely your external CSS stylesheet. Email clients typically block external CSS for security reasons, which means you have to use inline styles.

Comment: You need to combine everything into a single HTML markup with inline CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code with CSS inline moved from CSS from a file will actually work here, but this should be the direction of your code development.

Like in the comments: most likely the external CSS file will be blocked, so you need to add any styling in line.

```js
document
    .getElementById('signature-form')
    .addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get form input values
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
        var job = document.getElementById('job').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

        // Update signature output
        var signatureOutput = document.getElementById('signature-output');
        signatureOutput.querySelector('.name-surname').textContent =
            name + ' ' + surname;
        signatureOutput.querySelector('.job-desc').textContent = job;
        signatureOutput.querySelector('.phone').textContent = phone;

        // Scroll to the signature output
        signatureOutput.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    });

document.getElementById('copy-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var signatureOutput = document.getElementById('signature-output');

    // Create a range and select the signature output content
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(signatureOutput);

    // Copy the content to the clipboard
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand('copy');

    // Deselect the content
    selection.removeAllRanges();

    // Show a success message
    alert('Signature copied to clipboard!');
});
```

```css
.rectangle {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.name-surname {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.job-desc {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.phone {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.social-layout {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.logo-linkedin {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.logo-youtube {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.logo-facebook {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.hyperlinkurl {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.logomg {
    /* added inline CSS */
}

.map-gradient {
    /* added inline CSS */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div
            class="rectangle"
            style="
                position: absolute;
                width: 486px;
                height: 160px;
                left: 67px;
                top: 331px;
                background: #f0f9f5;
                border-radius: 8px;
            "
        ></div>

        <form id="signature-form">
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
            <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Surname" required />
            <input type="text" id="job" placeholder="Job" required />
            <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
            <button type="submit">Generate</button>
        </form>

        <div id="signature-output" class="signature-output">
            <span
                class="name-surname"
                style="
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 18px;
                    left: 87px;
                    top: 347px;
                    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 18px;
                    color: #3b785a;
                "
            ></span>
            <span
                class="job-desc"
                style="
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 160px;
                    height: 18px;
                    left: 87px;
                    top: 369px;
                    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 18px;
                    color: #3b785a;
                "
            ></span>
            <span
                class="phone"
                style="
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 120px;
                    height: 18px;
                    left: 87px;
                    top: 391px;
                    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    line-height: 18px;
                    color: #3b785a;
                "
            ></span>

            <div
                class="social-layout"
                style="
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    align-items: center;
                    padding: 0px;
                    gap: 16px;
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 80px;
                    height: 16px;
                    left: 87px;
                    top: 434px;
                "
            >
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com">
                    <img
                        src="logo-linkedin.png"
                        alt="logo-linkedin"
                        class="logo-linkedin"
                        style="
                            width: 16px;
                            height: 16px;
                            flex: none;
                            order: 0;
                            flex-grow: 0;
                        "
                    />
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.youtube.com">
                    <img
                        src="logo-youtube.png"
                        alt="logo-youtube"
                        class="logo-youtube"
                        style="
                            width: 16px;
                            height: 16px;
                            flex: none;
                            order: 1;
                            flex-grow: 0;
                        "
                    />
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
                    <img
                        src="logo-facebook.png"
                        alt="logo-facebook"
                        class="logo-facebook"
                        style="
                            width: 16px;
                            height: 16px;
                            flex: none;
                            order: 2;
                            flex-grow: 0;
                        "
                    />
                </a>
            </div>

            <a
                href="#"
                class="hyperlinkurl"
                style="
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 128px;
                    height: 17px;
                    left: 87px;
                    top: 458px;
                    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    line-height: 17px;
                    text-decoration-line: underline;
                    color: #3b785a;
                "
                >WebsiteUrl.com</a
            >

            <img
                src="logo.png"
                alt="Logo"
                class="logomg"
                style="
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 73.92px;
                    height: 48px;
                    left: 463px;
                    top: 427px;
                "
            />

            <div
                class="map-gradient"
                style="
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 307.92px;
                    height: 160px;
                    left: 201px;
                    top: 331px;
                    background: url(map-gradient.png);
                "
            ></div>
        </div>

        <button id="copy-button">Copy Signature</button>
    </body>
</html>
```